# How to exclude NUnit tests after using wildcard path in Teamcity build step

Tags: continuous-integration, nunit, teamcity, build-automation

I have a build step for running all of my unit tests, but I want to exclude some as well. I am using the following wildcard to run all of my tests:

> **/bin/debug/*Test*.dll

However, I want to exclude some tests with given names, so I've tried putting an exclude filter around these names:

> /src/TestToExclude1/bin/debug/TestToExclude1.dll
>   /src/TestToExclude2/bin/debug/TestToExclude2.dll

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work - it still tries to run the excluded tests. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: That should work. What happens if you match like: `**/src/TestToExclude1/bin/debug/TestToExclude1.dll` on the exclude filter?

Comment: Thanks. The filters were actually working, but I'd missed that some tests referenced other ones (see my answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that I was being too explicit in the exclude filter. Unfortunately, one of the excluded tests references another of the excluded tests, so copied it to its output folder. I wasn't excluding:

> /src/FirstTestToExclude/bin/debug/SecondTestToExclude.dll

I've changed the filter to:

> **/*SecondTestToExclude.dll